# Async ng-repeat for staggering rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there an async version of ng-repeat that permits rate-limiting of the rendering of the items in the collection?

Comment: There is none, cause there is no 'async js' in common sense at all.
Not sure why you need it thow. If you have i.e. million items - put them into virtual-repeat to render only visible.